# What is the strength of simple type set theory without infinity?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, type-theory

Lets have a multi-sorted first order theory, so a variable that range over all objects of some sort is denoted by a natural index over that variable as usual. So $x^i$ range over all objects of the $i^{th}$ type (sort). For every natural $n$ we have a sort $n$. So we have infinitely many types. Now as usual a formula is to be labeled *typed* formula if every atomic subformula of it is a typed atomic formula, where the latter is a formula of the general form $x^i=y^i$ or $x^i \in y^{i+1}$. We'll use an ambigious presentation of typed formulae through embracing the respective formula after hiding all of its type indices within two big brackes $\Big ( \Big )$, so $\Big {(}\exists x \exists y: x \in y \Big )$ in reality is the schema: $$ i=0,1,2,..\\ \exists x^i \exists y^{i+1}: x^i \in y^{i+1}$$

Now we write the axioms of this theory:

**Extensionality:** $$\Big{(} \forall x \, \forall y : \forall z \, (z \in x \iff z \in y ) \to x=y \Big )$$

**Comprehension:** if $\phi$ is a typed formul in which $``y,z_1,..,z_n"$ is all variable symbols occurring free in it, then:$$ \Big{(} \forall z_1,..,\forall z_n: \exists x \, \forall y \, (y \in x \iff \phi )\Big )$$

The equality axioms are written in a sorted manner as usual.

I consider this theory to really be a part of LOGIC, that one may call it the logic of typed sets. Of course if we add an axiom of Infinity to it like:

**Infinity:** $\Big {(} \exists x : \exists y \, ( x \in y \land \forall z \in y \exists w \in y: w \subsetneq z) \Big )$

Then this is clearly a particularity that cannot be attibuted to a general logic rule about typed sets. So, the theory becomes a mathematical extension of a logical theory.

I'm concerned with the logical part, that is the multi-sorted first order logic with the sorted equality axioms and the above first two axiom schemata. Which I know of it being weaker than $\sf PA$. What is the consistency strength of it? In particular, what is the proof-theoretic ordinal of it?